# Requirement Traceability in TDD?

Tags: tdd, bdd, agile

Its always said that the requirements should be traceable but when we talk about agile development, it is quite difficult.
**My question is that how requirement traceability (or requirement change management) is managed in agile and specifically Test First Development or Test Driven Development?**

Comment: You said you got your answer. So are you going to accept one of the answers? :-)

Comment: i got the idea how its currently done. i am doing research on requirements traceability in TDD, so have to see every possible way of its implementation. In short, i will accept every single answer and then  explore them one by one in detail :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TDD or BDD (Behavior Driven Development) your requirements are captured in your tests.

You can either map your tests against actual requirements (more TDD model) or actually use your tests as the requirements for your product (more BDD model).

For a great example of what you can do with BDD and tests functioning as requirements, checkout [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) and [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) from the Ruby/Rails world.

Having worked in an FDA regulated environment, with responsibility for Quality Engineering, I can tell you that TDD/BDD fits incredibly well into the model an FDA Auditor is working against.

A BDD model will allow you to trace through:

- Requirements -> Tests
- Tests -> Implementation
- Implementation Execution -> Test Results

Answer (score 2):

When the requirements change, the tests change. Remember that the tests are the living documentation and requirements specification. Therefore, the change is seamless.

For example: Requirements changes lead to test expectation changes, which in turn lead to code changes.

Answer (score 1):

May be I am missing something but TFD or TDD is at the unit testing level. What you are referring to is managed by [Traceability matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceability_matrix) and/or [acceptance tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing) in my opinion.

Comment: TDD is not necessarily at the unit testing level. That is just the place where developers most often interact with it.

Comment: I am taking TDD as a whole development cycle in which we have requirements and then we create testlists and then create unit tests from it and so on. My question was how requirements traceability is managed in Agile and particularly in TDD where we may not have specification document and requirements keep on changing all the time. In that case how we kept the track of the requirements incase of any change?

Answer (score 0):

Agile traceability is very tricky to begin with, A lot of tools are currently available that claim to provide traceability by documenting user stories, or generating requirements from user stories or in TDD from Tests.

The point when we consider any Agile method is not having to emphasize on documentation(Read the  [Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/). So, I am not sure how Agile will have traceability and also streamline with its core principles.

Answer (score 0):

Lately found a traceablity, requirement management tool online. [http://code.google.com/p/ultimate-trace/ Ultimate Trace] Give it a try. It saved us a lot of effort maintaining traceability.

Answer (score 0):

Re-read the manifesto.  It values the right-half of the four statements more, but note that it reads, "there is value on the left."  Which means that documents are not inherently evil or forbidden, they should just be view cautiously and should not overrule the real purpose of the work.  That being said, electronic traceability tools have been out there for years, some more elegant and some absolute beasts.  Tracking from test cases back to the stories defining them is important, especially as systems move into R&M.  Otherwise, as systems grow you trade off chasing down documentation of the system for chasing down components of the system.  Traceability may be handled by naming conventions, some feature of a configuration/code baseline tool, by a test suite tool, or by an RTM.  The old, old school approach was an spreadsheet (slit my wrists, please), but we have come a long way by now.